# Capture all event targets from mouseover when user clicks, then stop

Tags: javascript

I'd like to record all `event.target` that mouse encounters after user clicks anywhere and stop recording after he releases click. So far I've come up with this which doesn't stop recording after mouseup and I don't know why.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.addEventListener('mouseover', record);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', removeListener);
})

function record(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}

function removeListener() {
  document.removeEventListener('mouseover', record);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', removeListener);
}
```

```html
<div class='toto'>Toto</div>
<div class='toto'>Toto</div>
<div class='toto'>Toto</div>
<div class='toto'>Toto</div>
```

**EDIT : Answer & Explanation**

`addEventListener('click')` triggers on mouseup, therefore the sequence was as follow :

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //Following would start once mouseup
    document.addEventListener('mouseover', record);
    //Following never triggers cause mouse is already up
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', removeListener);
})
```

Solution as stated in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238186/8162252) is to replace `'click'` with `'mousedown'`. It triggers immediatly after mouse is click is pressed, not released :

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  document.addEventListener('mouseover', record);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', removeListener);
})
```

Comment: Please post a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to receive useful help.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxaGRZ If I click, it starts recording. If I mouseup, it doesn't stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of click event, you should use mousedown

I forked your codepen and you can see the result: https://codepen.io/Lazzaro83/pen/EeoxEW

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  document.addEventListener('mouseover', record);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', removeListener);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you are putting one listener inside another, this isn't a reliable way to do so because terms of ms of execution, remember JS is not that "sequential" do not worry and let the three listener to live, a better way of do the thing you want to is make a global variable that works like a switch :

```
  let switch = false;

   document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); 
   switch = true;
   }); 
   document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
    if (switch){
    console.log(e.target);
    }
   });
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   switch = false;
   }) ;
```

this is a project i did with a blackboard, have many techniques as relegation:

https://codepen.io/LeonAGA/pen/eyWpMV

regards!